# Internal Server Error while Verifying Order in Endurance Storage

Tags: rest, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am verifying order using the below REST Call in Mozilla Poster

https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder

and the jSON payload for this call is:-

```
      {
      "parameters": [
         {
         "location": 138124,  
         "packageId": 240,
         "osFormatType": {
         "id": 12,
         "keyName": "LINUX"
         },
         "complexType": 
           SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise",
         "prices": [
         {
          "id": 45064   # Endurance Storage
         },
         {
          "id": 45104   # Bloack Storage
         },
         {
          "id": 45074   # 0.25 IOPS/GB
         },
         {
          "id": 45354   # 100 GB Storage space
         },
         {
          "id": 6028    # 5 GB Snapshot space
         }
         ],
         "quantity": 1
        }
         ]
        }
```

Call used for snap shot space is :-

```
   https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/240/getItemPrices?objectFilter={%22itemPrices%22: {%22categories%22: {%22categoryCode%22: {%22operation%22: %22storage_snapshot_space%22}}}}
```

But still I am facing issue. Error I got is 500 Internal Server Error.

Please assist me in same. Thanks in Advance

Comment: mmm, the error 500 suggest that your request has a worng format, just in case did you remove the comments from the json? (e.g # Bloack Storage). Make sure that your json has the correct format, you can use this validator http://jsonlint.com/ . Then you need to make sure that the prices are the correct.

Comment: @NelsonRaulCaberoMendoza I have removed comments also. Let me validate with jsonlint.com

Comment: @NelsonRaulCaberoMendoza I validated it with jsonlint.com and result for same is Valid Json

Comment: Also make sure that your user has the enough permisions to make orders. it is better if you first try with the master user of the account in order to avoid a permission issue.

Comment: @NelsonRaulCaberoMendoza thanks for your support. It was permission issue and worked with different credentials successfully. One more question from my side:- How will I be able to delete the created storages that are not attached to any VM through rest call... ?

Comment: see this https://sldn.softlayer.com/node/274103 you can use the cancelService or cancelItem methods. Basically you have to cancel the associated billing item of the storage. also look in the forum I think there is a similar question

Comment: @NelsonRaulCaberoMendoza I tried to cancel a storage but for that we need to have billing Id of that storage. i want to know when does billing Id generated..? Is it after attaching any VM to storage or at the time of placing order itself? Thanks in advance

Comment: the billing id is created when the order is approved and is provisioned, when your storage is ready the billing id is already created as well.

Comment: Did you read the documentation I sent you? there is an example about how to get the billing item from an endurance device

Comment: yes I read and it is quite useful. Thanks a lot @NelsonRaulCaberoMendoza

Comment: @NelsonRaulCaberoMendoza I deleted a storage using this call :- https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Item/billingId/cancelItem

but still I am able to see storage corresponding to this billing id using below call:- 
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[id,username,nasType,storageType,%20billingItem[description,location[id,longName]]]&objectFilter={%22networkStorage%22:{%22nasType%22:{%22operation%22:%22ISCSI%22},%22billingItem%22:{%22description%22:{%22operation%22:%22Endurance%20Storage%22}}}}
what is the problem..?

Comment: Just wait, it takes some time even if you delete it using the portal. In case it takes long time submit a ticket to know what is going on

Answer (score 0):

There were some mistakes in your template:

1. The start quote (") for
   "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise" value
   is missing.
2. The item price: "45354" refers to : "2000 GB Storage Space"
3. The id: "6028" refers to "itemId". You should specify the
   "price identifier" ("id" property using [SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices)) instead of "itemId"

Try this template:

```
{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "location":138124,
         "packageId":240,
         "osFormatType":{  
            "id":12,
            "keyName":"LINUX"
         },
         "complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise",
         "prices":[  
            {  
               "id":45064  # Endurance Storage
            },
            {  
               "id":45104  # Block Storage
            },
            {  
               "id":45074  # 0.25 IOPS/GB  
            },
            {  
               "id":45214  # 100 GB Storage space
            },
            {  
               "id":46126  # 5 GB Snapshot space
            }
         ],
         "quantity":1
      }
   ]
}
```

**Some important references:**

- [Location-based Pricing and
  You](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/location-based-pricing-and-you)
- [Ordering and Configuring Endurance and Performance Block Storage
  with
  VMware@SoftLayer](https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/content/ordering-and-configuring-endurance-and-performance-block-storage-vmwaresoftlayer)

Comment: I used your JSON payload but still getting 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Could you provide the exception that you have? (error value)